# Are there any methods to quantify H2O2 (hydrogen peroxide) which don't rely on horseradish peroxidase?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I can't use HRP since my substrates interfere with it and I need a real-time method because I want to measure kinetic parameters of some oxidases.

Comment: Titrate it with Potassium permanganate? http://phs.prs.k12.nj.us/rcorell/LabREDOXAnalH2O2.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I need a real-time method because I need to measure kinetics parameters for oxidases.

Answer (score 2):

Amperometric detection of H2O2 can be performed without HRP, and gives high-resolution real-time readings.

You will find many different type of electrodes that are used in the literature to detect H2O2, including for instance [MnO2-coated carbon paste microelectrodes](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1997/AN/a701723e) or [gold electrodes derivatized with cytochrome c](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359511312001328).

Commercial electrodes also exists. For instance [these from WPI](http://www.wpiinc.com/index.php?submenu=phybiohypxsen&class0_0=31&class1_0=323&class2_0=&class3_0=&class4_0=&submit=Filter&xsearch_id=products_type_search&src=directory&srctype=products_lister&view=products) are based on derivatized carbon fibers (although they do not specify with what, so I would not exclude HRP...)

Another option is that of using the H2O2-sensitive dye H2DCF (dihydro-dichlorofluorescein).

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion (H2DCF) I looked more into it and I found several other options: dihydrocalcein AM, dihydrorhodamines, dihydroethidium and Europium-tetracycline. All of them seems to not require another enzyme. Any experience with one of these?

Comment: No sorry, I actually found that while looking for amperometric detection and I thought I would add it as another option. The thing that I would start and check is their specificity, I am under the impression that they are ROS detectors rather than H2O2 detectors, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a purely chemical assay, [Manganese dioxide (MnO2) will react to produce oxygen from hydrogen peroxide](http://depts.washington.edu/chem/facilserv/lecturedemo/DecompositionofH2O2withMnO2-UWDept.ofChemistry.html), which can be detected spectroscopically or by means of direct chemical analysis.

I think the enzymatic assay is less environmentally challenging and produces colorometric results directly, which is probably why it is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the kinetic parameters of oxidases you could also look into measuring the oxygen concentration directly. Oxygen sensors are much more common than H2O2 sensors, and I know small setups (1 ml samples) based on a fluorescent dye based probe are available.

Comment: can you please tell me more about this fluorescent dye probe for measuring oxygen?